# how to push javascript function return value as code.gs function variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, client-server

I have created a function to get select option value.

**Javascript**

```
function filter_market(){
var kk = document.getElementById('filter_market').value;
console.log("market selected "+kk);
return kk;
}
```

I wanted to push this return value into the code.gs file as an filter value.

**code.gs**

```
function readData(spreadsheetId,range){
var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range);
return result;
}
```

Please help me on filtering the data using appscript.

Comment: you've posted two functions ... how are they even related?

Comment: I am able to get the table with using readData function from code.gs.

Dynamically i wanted change the market value from html page. filter_market is the function created in javascript.

as and when filter_market value changes that should be applied to the code.gs function.

Is this possible??

Comment: You need to look at [google.script.run()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to see how to communicate between client (browser) and server (Spreadsheet).  Unless `spreadsheetId` and `range` are global variables your `readData` won't work as is.

Comment: Hi WizEd,

Added like below but still issue persists...

    function filter_market(){
    var kk = document.getElementById('filter_market').value;
    console.log("market selected "+kk);
    google.script.run.filter_market(kk);
    }

Please suggest

Comment: You would need to eidt your question to show your entire relevant code inluding `google.script.run() `  in order to allow troubleshooting.